# iOS 5 tab view changed push the root controller (storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

i have a uitabbarcontroller which has 3 items. each item has its own navigation controller.
for example in tab 1 the user navigates to other subview and then changes to tab 2 and then back to the tab 1. the tab one shows the subview. how can i push the root view controller instead of the subview?
my uitabbarcontroller is customized and has:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

is it the right place to do some kind of pushrootviewcontroller?
how to get the controller?

## edit:

i have the following implemented

```
UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>
```

and

```
    -(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
     {
      if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
         {
           NSLog(@"test%@",@"test");
 [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
         }
      }
```

nslog output can be seen in the debugger but popto root doesnt work. any idea?

Comment: So you mean, you want the first tab pop back to its initial view, once user switches from tab 1 to tab 2 and returns to tab 1?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i want.

Comment: one approach could be to add [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO] in -(void)viewDidDisappear

Comment: yeah that one i though too but i have 2 subviews on a view. so i have to to that on each, but that would raise a problem that i will never get to that last subview.

Comment: By subView you mean this is your hierarchy: UINavigationController > RootViewController > ViewController1 > ViewController2 ? and user is in ViewController2 ?

Comment: exactly the hierarchy is like you said. and all those are on one tab. so tab is selected bakch to this one then i want to jump to rootviewcontroller regardless of which view was on the screen. so on both cases VC1 and VC2.

Comment: I guess, now I understand what you want. Instead of adding popToRootViewControllerAnimated to every childView in the hierrachy, you want to put it in a single place, where is will be called upon switching tabs. I haven't tried it, but you may want to try subClassing your UITabBarController (as the parent of all viewControllers), and once tabs are switched, it pops the viewController that is just disappeared to its rootViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the code should look like this. and now it works the way i wanted.

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
}
```